# How to reduce calls of StopWatch or System.currentTimeMillis in Java / Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stopwatch

I am using Stopwatch (internally using `System.currentTimeMillis())` to calculate every API time for execution and completion. I see that there is lots of issues related to `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Is there any alternate or better way to calculate time for every API and alternate to `System.currentTimeMillis()`. `System.nanotime()` is slower compared using `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Linux so it won't work.

StopWatch code:-

```java
public stopwatch{
private final long start;
    public Stopwatch() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public double elapsedTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (now - start) / 1000.0;
    }}
```

API code:

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public String endPoint(){
  StopWatch  stopWatch = new StopWatch  ();
  //Some code
  long timeTakenForTApi = stopWatch.elapsedTime();
}
```

Comment: > I see that there is lots of issue. Which ones?

Comment: 1) Is there is something Alternate to System.CurrentTimeMillis().

Comment: 2) Is there anything alternate way, IF I can reduce calls of Stopwatch in ever API as , I have to use Stop watch object a the start of every end point to calculate the time

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us any specific requirements, so I can only make educated guesses.

I reckon, you want to collect performance metrics for your API calls and feed them to some kind of metrics data analyzing tool like Prometheus, Dynatrace or AWS Cloudwatch?

If that's the case, I wouldn't start reinventing the wheel. Did you have a look at https://micrometer.io?

You would then either use a `Timer` programatically or use the baked in `@Timed` annotation on your controller methods like so:

```
@Timed
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public String endPoint(){
  //Some code
}
```

Comment: @GetMapping("/endpoint1")
public String endpoint1(){


StopWatch  stopWatch = new StopWatch  ();

//Some code

long timeTakenForTApi = stopWatch.elapsedTime();
log.info("total time taken "+ timeTakenForTApi);
save.setTimeTakenForApi(timeTakenForTApi);
}

@GetMapping("/endpoint2")
public String endpoint2(){


StopWatch  stopWatch = new StopWatch  ();

//Some code

long timeTakenForTApi = stopWatch.elapsedTime();
log.info("total time taken "+ timeTakenForTApi);
save.setTimeTakenForApi(timeTakenForTApi);
}

Comment: Thanks for your help, But My convert is I"m create StopWatch object in every endpoint. Lets Say I've 5 api in controller and I've to create 5 StopWatch object inside every api service, My concern is do we have anything alternatge instead of creating object in every Api and also I want to save time which it takes for execution of every api end point it hits and completes execution.

Comment: Also another concern is do we Have Anything other than System.CurrentTimeMIllis for calculating time and performance and I've to save that time for logs and database.

Comment: Like I said in my answer: Use MicroMeter and put `@Timed` on your endpoints. You could even write a custom Aspect to get rid of the `@Timed` annotation as well, if you want to monitor _all_ your endpoints. Read the docs. It's all there.